# uploading image to server in Socket.io from IOS + Swift

Tags: ios, swift, sockets, websocket, socket.io

I'm using socket.io Library to make an chat app. 
Now I'm trying to upload image to server from IOS app using swift3.0

I tried creating bytearray and send it as string to server but it returns corrupted image.

```
     var byteArray = (UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)?.base64EncodedString(options: .lineLength64Characters))! as String

    let base64encoding = imageData.base64EncodedString()

    let string = (String (format: "{\"text\":\"\",\"chatId\":\"%@\",\"identifier\":1476869117744,\"sessionId\":\"1476869062088\",\"attachments\":[{\"type\":\"IMAGE\",\"data\":{\"size\": \"%@\", \"name\": \"%@\", \"modifiedOn\": \"2016-12-12\", \"file\":\"%@\" }}]}","122","1233.22","photo.jpg",base64encoding))
```

Does anyone have any idea, how to upload image to server using socket.io in IOS.

Comment: have you got any solution. i am facing same problem?

Comment: @AbecedarioPoint Yes, it worked for me, Let me post solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Here is the method I Have created to post image to server. Hope this one helps you.**

```
{

         LoadingIndicatorView.show(loadingView!)

        LoadingIndicatorView.show("Please Wait...")

            let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.5)!
            let length: Float = Float(imageData.count)
            let fileSizeString = "\(length)"

            if let data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) {
                let filename = getDocumentsDirectory().appendingPathComponent("copy.png")
                try? data.write(to: filename)
                     // print(filename)
            }

                    let keys = ["size" ,"name","modifiedOn","file"]
                    let values = [fileSizeString,"photo.jpg","2016-12-12",imageData] as [Any]



                    let dictionary = NSMutableDictionary(objects: values, forKeys: keys as [NSCopying])

                    let SubscriptionDict: [String : AnyObject] = [
                        "type" :"IMAGE" as AnyObject,
                         "data" :dictionary as AnyObject

                    ]
            let Arr1 = NSMutableArray()
            Arr1.add(SubscriptionDict)
            let chatDict: [String : AnyObject] = [

                "text": "" as AnyObject,
                "chatId":chatInfoDict?["_id"] as! String as AnyObject ,
                "identifier":"147853531XXXX" as AnyObject,
                "sessionId":"14785348XXXXX" as AnyObject,
                "attachments" :Arr1 as AnyObject

            ]


            FAWebSocketClient.sharedClient.doEvent(eventName: "MESSAGE_CREATE", tmp: chatDict as AnyObject!);

        }
```